# Debo optimizar este código para bajar el tiempo de ejecución

Tags: python, matrices, numpy, jupyter

Debo optimizar este código para bajar el tiempo de ejecución, ya que, debo generar 9 matrices de 210 columnas x 1 millón de filas de un data set que esta repartido en 3 carpetas y cada de estas carpetas tiene 3 subcarpetas, llegando a un total de 9 carpetas con archivos.

```
import os, fnmatch
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

ruta = r"C:\Users\..."
count = 0
print("Leyendo directorios....")
print("")

for archivo in os.listdir(ruta):
    for archivo2 in os.listdir(ruta + "\\" + archivo):
        if(archivo2 == "3+_19"): 
            break        
        for archivo3 in os.listdir(ruta + "\\" + archivo + "\\" + archivo2):
            if fnmatch.fnmatchcase(archivo3, '*.lbp'):
                continue
            elif fnmatch.fnmatchcase(archivo3, '*.py'):
                continue
            elif fnmatch.fnmatchcase(archivo3, '*.npy'):
                continue
            columnas = np.genfromtxt(ruta +"/"+ archivo +"/"+ archivo2 +"/"+ archivo3, delimiter = ',')
            columnas = columnas.reshape(1000000, 1)
            if(count > 0):
                print("Generado matriz con el archivo: " + archivo3 + " de la subcarpeta: " + archivo2 + " de la carpeta: " + archivo)
                matriz = np.append(matriz, columnas, axis=1)
            else:
                matriz = columnas
            count = count + 1
            np.savetxt("Imagen"+ archivo2 +".npy", matriz, fmt='%F', delimiter=',')
print("")
print("****************")
print("Matrices Lista!!")
print("****************")
```

Comment: Por favor, identifica cual es la línea crítica (la operación lenta) y construye un [ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) con el cual podamos probar sin tener que crear directorios y archivos monstruosos.

Comment: Creo que pueden ser los 3 for, pero linea critica en especifico no se cual podría ser.

Comment: Perfila tu código e identifica donde está el problema. Revisa [Los perfiladores de Python](https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/profile.html). Te será de gran ayuda a futuro.

Comment: Lo voy a leer muchas gracias.